# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) (mysqld.sock file is missing)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

On an Ubuntu VPS. I installed mysql via command line. `mysql start` results in:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

mysqld.sock is indeed missing.

Using `find / -type s` there is no mysqld.sock or any other mysql sock files.

Result of `sudo service mysql status`

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Mon 2020-05-04 22:42:17 EDT; 13s ago
  Process: 21907 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
 Main PID: 7884 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS); Control PID: 21926 (mysqld)
    Tasks: 14 (limit: 2318)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           ├─21926 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
           └─21928 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

May 04 22:42:17 qnachatphpwebsockets systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
```

Comment: Can you run `sudo service mysql restart`. And then `sudo service mysql status` to check if it's active

Comment: `sudo service mysql restart` seems to never resolve. I added the result of `sudo service mysql status` to the question.

Comment: It should be `active (running)`. It seems it's starting maybe you should wait a few seconds or is it stuck it this ?

Comment: No wait I get "Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."